# How do I use key inputs?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, keyboard-events

I am creating a small game for a java project (Swing GUI), we have to use a MVC pattern and I got the basic model and view down. I just can't get to understand how to use the keyboard keys to -for example- increment the X position of my character. What library should I use?

Here is my code (it's my first time coding):

```
/*A Thing type object can stand on a Tile,the characters and items class implement this interface.*/

public interface Thing {           
    public void attacked(int x);     
}                                   

public abstract class Character implements Thing{
    protected int health;
    protected int position[]=new int[2];
    protected int direction;
    protected void setHealth(int hp){
        this.health=hp;
    }
    public int getHealth(){
        return this.health;
    }
    public void setPositionX(int x){
        this.position[0]=x;
    }
    public void setPositionY(int y){
        this.position[1]=y;
    }
    public int getPositionX(){
        return this.position[0];
    }
    public int getPositionY(){
        return this.position[1];
    }
    public void setDirection(int x){
        this.direction=x;
    }
    public int getDirection(){
        return this.direction;
    }
    public void moveUp(){
        int posy=this.getPositionY();
        this.setPositionY(posy+1);
    }
    public void moveDown(){
        int posy=this.getPositionY();
        this.setPositionY(posy-1);
    }
    public void moveLeft(){
        int posx=this.getPositionX();
        this.setPositionX(posx-1);
    }
    public void moveRight(){
        int posx=this.getPositionX();
        this.setPositionX(posx+1);
    }
    public void attack(){

    }
    public void heavyAttack(){

    }
}
/*Only one type of character,just to have a really basic code to test then improve it*/

public class Mage extends Character{
    public Mage(){
        this.setHealth(5);
        this.setPositionX(3);
        this.setPositionY(3);
    }
    public void attacked(int x){
        this.setHealth(this.getHealth()-x);
    }
}

/*A Tile is a space on which a character/item (Thing) can stand,the level is a matrice of tiles*/

public class Tile {
    private Thing[] occupant;
    public Tile(){
        this.occupant=new Thing[1];
    }
    public Thing getOccupant(){
        return this.occupant[0];
    }
    public void addThing(Thing a){
        this.occupant[0]=a;
    }
    public void removeThing(){
        this.occupant[0]=null;
    }
}

public class Terrain {
    private String name;
    private Tile[][] checker;
    private int sizeX;
    private int sizeY;
    public Terrain(int x,int y,String Name){
        this.name=Name;
        this.sizeX=x;
        this.sizeY=y;
        this.checker= new Tile[y][x];
        for (int i=0; i<y; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
                this.checker[i][j]=new Tile();
            }
        }
    }
    public int getSizeX(){
        return sizeX;
    }
    public int getSizeY(){
        return sizeY;
    }
    public Thing getTileOccupant(int x,int y){
        return this.checker[y][x].getOccupant();
    }
    public void Spawn(Thing t,int x,int y){
        this.checker[y][x].addThing(t);
    }

}

/* The View,This was really just to test it out so it only shows the tiles and the mage sprite*/

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class myPanel extends JPanel {
    private Terrain terrain;
    public myPanel(Terrain checker){
        this.terrain=checker;
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        File file=new File("D:\\workspace\\Projet INFO-H-200\\src\\Images\\soltest.png");
        BufferedImage sol=null;
        try{
            sol=ImageIO.read(file);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        file=new File("D:\\workspace\\Projet INFO-H-200\\src\\Images\\mage.png");
        BufferedImage mage=null;
        try{
            mage=ImageIO.read(file);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i=0;i<terrain.getSizeY();i++){
            for (int j=0;j<terrain.getSizeX();j++){
                g.drawImage(sol, 33*j,33*i, null);
                if (terrain.getTileOccupant(j,i)!=null){
                    g.drawImage(mage, 33*j, 33*i, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Mage blubu=new Mage();
        Terrain terrain=new Terrain(10,10,"Test");
        terrain.Spawn(blubu, blubu.getPositionX(), blubu.getPositionY());

        Controler controler=new Controler(blubu);
        JFrame mainWindow=new JFrame();
        mainWindow.setSize(new Dimension(1000,800));
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //au centre
        mainWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());//gérer les placements
        mainWindow.add(new myPanel(terrain), BorderLayout.CENTER); //on ajoute le panel au centre
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        mainWindow.toFront();
    }
}
```

Comment: Console: Scanner, BufferedReader. GUI: KeyListener

Comment: For better more specific help, please ask a more specific and informative question, including pertinent code and details of your problem. For instance if this were a Swing GUI (something you never tell us), a KeyListener would likely not be something most Swing experts would recommend.

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991986/pong-controls-with-keylistener/12992048#12992048). Also please have a look at [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a522444%20keylistener).

Comment: Thank you very much,with KeyListeners I had the problem of never having focus but I didn't know why. I will definitely try the other method though.

Comment: @zoisus: and that's exactly why you shouldn't use a KeyListener -- use Key Bindings.

Comment: And yes I am using a Swing GUI,I will first try to make it work by myself otherwise I will never learn how to code alone, but if I really can't make it I will post my code to ask for deeper help,thank you @HovercraftFullOfEels!

Comment: Never read in images within a paintComponent method. 1) It's not necessary to keep reading in the same image over and over. Read it in once in a constructor, assign it to a field and be done with it. 2) This unnecessarily slows down painting and thus slows the perceived responsiveness of your GUI.

Comment: Your posted code is missing the Controler class.

Comment: I haven't written the controler yet,it's what I'm trying to do at the moment (reading the docs). Sorry for the slow answers but I'm running left and right and coding in between

Comment: Thank you for the paintComponent tip,I'll change that asap