# About Key Bindings in Java

Tags: java, awt, key-bindings

People here keep suggesting to me to use Key Bindings in my Java 2D games instead of Key Listener.

So I learned it and I'd like to know wether I understand correctly how to use it.

Let's say I have a game, with two playes, each player can push 5 buttons.

Player 1:

- <kbd>UP</kbd> arrow - move forward
- <kbd>LEFT</kbd> arrow - change angle of movement
- <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> arrow - change angle of movement
- <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key - fire missile
- <kbd>L</kbd> key - fire secondary missile

Player 2:

- <kbd>W</kbd> key - move forward
- <kbd>A</kbd> key - change angle of movement
- <kbd>D</kbd> key - change angle of movement
- <kbd>CAPS-LOCK</kbd> key - fire missile
- 'Z' key - fire secondary missile

If I want the program to react differently to each one of the different key-presses, than this is what I have to do: (?)

1. Create **10** new nested classes extending AbstractAction, inside
   the class that runs most of the game logic.
2. Create an instance of
   every one of these **10** new classes, and bind each one to a key.

Is this correct? Is it really logical to create 10 new classes only for pushing buttons?
I want to know if I understand correctly how to use Key Bindings, so I can start programming with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Is this correct? Is it really logical to create 10 new classes only for pushing buttons?"*

The answer is YES. You do need to create 10 different instances. It's not difficult. You can either create a helper class or you can just copy and paste something like this

```
Action leftAction = new AbstractAction(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // do something when left button pressed;
    }
};

InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();

inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "leftAction");
actionMap.put("leftAction", leftAction);  <----
```

For each different action, just copy and paste the `Action` code, change the variable, and the action to perform, and input into the `InputMap` and the `ActionMap` accordingly.

I use both ways for different scenarios. For graphics i prefer the above way. For things like menus, I tend to use a separate class

Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20844242/2587435)

Comment: I understand I need to create 10 different instances. But do I need to create 10 different *classes*? (each one with an instance?)

Comment: What you wrote above: What does it do? Does it create a new class named leftAction, the extends AbstractAction? Or does it create a new instance of AbstractAction, and then overrides actionPerformed() for that specific instance?

Comment: Well technically with the code above, you _are_ creating an annonymous class. you would have to repeat the the top part of my code 10 times for tem different actions.

Comment: It's what you can an anonymous class. Yes the `leftAction` is the varible of the class. `AbstractAction` is a class that _need_ to override the `actionPerformed`, just like an ActionListener class

Comment: So to answer my question in the second comment: What you wrote above equals to 'creating a new class named leftAction, that extends AbstractAction'? Or is it just another instance of AbstractAction?

Comment: It's creating a whole new class just in a shorter way. You cant create an instance of Abstract action. You have to extend it. So the above is kinda like saying `class leftAction extends AbstractAction`. So you really are creating a class, not instantiating one. You can look more into anonymous classes if you're really interested. That's what you would call `leftAction`

Comment: When using what you wrote inside another method, say a constructor. I need a semicolon after the last '}', correct? I get an error if I don't.

Comment: Yes you do need a semi-colon. Sorry, I forgot that

Comment: By the way you got another small error. I suggest you fix it so people in the futue looking for help will get the right code :) This: inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, "leftAction");
Should be this: inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT), "leftAction");
(Or am I wrong?)

Comment: ALso, last question. You said the code above creates an anonymous class. But in the same time, it creates an instance of that class. Am I correct?

Comment: Not exactly, `AbstractAction` is an abstract class which can't be instantiated. Only extended. Try it `Action action = new AbstractAction();`. It won't work

Comment: So how can you refer to the instance leftAction if it hasn't been created? Or are you refering to a class, not an instance?
Also, sorry to bother you, but VK_RIGHT doesn't work. However RIGHT does. (Might want to change that for people looking here in the future)

Comment: Take a look at [Anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). [The really big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) can answer a lot of question you have.

Answer (score 2):

```
public TestKeyBindings02() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    InputMap im = panel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap am = panel.getActionMap();

    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "RightArrow");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "LeftArrow");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "UpArrow");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "DownArrow");

    am.put("RightArrow", new ArrowAction("RightArrow"));
    am.put("LeftArrow", new ArrowAction("LeftArrow"));
    am.put("UpArrow", new ArrowAction("UpArrow"));
    am.put("DownArrow", new ArrowAction("DownArrow"));
}

public class ArrowAction extends AbstractAction {

    private String cmd;

    public ArrowAction(String cmd) {
        this.cmd = cmd;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("LeftArrow")) {
            System.out.println("The left arrow was pressed!");
        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("RightArrow")) {
            System.out.println("The right arrow was pressed!");
        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("UpArrow")) {
            System.out.println("The up arrow was pressed!");
        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("DownArrow")) {
            System.out.println("The down arrow was pressed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422488/java-keybindings)

Comment: [not sure, please to see code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7940227/714968)

Answer (score 1):

Personaly, when I was using keyBindings I would create an inner class extending abstractAction for each action, then create an instance of this inner class and bind it to a key like `put("left", ActionLeft);`, for example. So basically I did the two steps you've described and that worked.

You could also just create instances of anonymus classes and then bind those instances just the same way.