# key bindings without creating new instance every time

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

checkout the first answer of this post: [Java Keybindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422488/java-keybindings)
especially, these rows:

```
am.put("RightArrow", new ArrowAction("RightArrow"));
am.put("LeftArrow", new ArrowAction("LeftArrow"));
am.put("UpArrow", new ArrowAction("UpArrow"));
am.put("DownArrow", new ArrowAction("DownArrow"));
```

he is always creating new object of his class, is it possible to do without it? check my code below, I tried all methods of ActionEvent's variable "e", but all of them were unuseful. Is it good to create every time new object? 
I have this so far:

```
action = new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // can I determine here what action was performed?
        }
    };

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left_arrow");
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right_arrow");
    actionMap.put("left_arrow", action);
actionMap.put("right_arrow", action);
```

Comment: try ActionEvent.getActionCommand(). It may or may not differentiate for your "left_arrow" / "right_arrow" events

Comment: I'm getting null from this method.

Comment: then there's no way to do it

Comment: IMO it can slack an application a little if there are many bindings using very often or no?