# Pause Button in Java Game

Tags: java

I've been working on my first "game" in Java, Pong, and I feel as if I'm ready to implement a pause button. With my current code, pressing escape (which is meant to make state = State.PAUSE, pausing the game) makes the screen flicker, and occasionally pause. The game has been running well until so far, so it'd be preferable if I could change my code as little as possible, if possible. My current code:

gameloop in main() running ~60 fps:

```
int fps = 60;
double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;
double delta = 0;
long now;
long lastTime = System.nanoTime();

while (true) {

    now = System.nanoTime();
    delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
    timer += now - lastTime;
    lastTime = now;

    if(delta >= 1){
        //refreshes Keyboard
        p.key.nUpdate();
        //refreshes game
        p.nUpdate();
        //refreshes graphics
        p.nPaint();
        ticks++;
        delta--;
    }

    if(timer >= 1000000000){
        log();
        ticks = 0;
        timer = 0;
    }
}
```

in Keyboard, I assign all needed values to booleans:

```
public class Keyboard extends KeyAdapter implements KeyListener {

    private boolean[] keys;
    public boolean escape;
    public boolean r;

    public Keyboard(){
        keys = new boolean[256];
    }

    public void nUpdate(){
        escape = keys[KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE];
        r = keys[KeyEvent.VK_R];
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
    }
```

my game window, update methods:

```
public void nUpdate() {
    if (key.r) newMatch();
    if (key.escape) pause();

    if (state == State.GAME) {...}
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    switch (state) {
    case GAME: ...
    case PAUSE: ...
}

public void nPaint() {
    repaint();
}

public void pause() {
    if (state == State.GAME) state = State.PAUSE;
    else if (state == State.PAUSE) state = State.GAME;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a simpler or cleaner way to pause the game, or at least stop it from flickering during pause (or being paused/unpaused repeatedly). I also apologize in advance if I have too much/not enough/unclean code, absolutely any help is appreciated

Comment: *"I'm wondering if there is a simpler or cleaner way to pause the game"* - Stop/pause the update thread and/or change the logic it performs while paused.  I would also consider using the Key Bindings API of `KeyListener`, as it will generally reduce the number of problems you will have.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: While that specific tutorial was a little hard to understand, I followed your advice with the KeyBindings (and looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422488/java-keybindings)); it works perfectly and is easier to implement. Thanks a bunch