# Simple program with KeyAdapter can't register single keys after pressing down several. Code solution?

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm just trying to get the basics down when it comes to simple drawing programs. I have a program that draws a rectangle and then lets me move it in any direction. I use a thread for smooth actions. However, what kind of bothers me is that if I press down three keys and release two of them, the program won't detect the third, thus leaving the rectangle stationary.

Am I asking for too much here, or might it be hardware related? I have a pretty cheap keyboard.

Here's the full program if you want to go for a ride.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Boxxy extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    int xPos, yPos, xDir, yDir;
    MyPanel panel;
    ImageIcon ii;
    Image i;


    public Boxxy() {
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel = new MyPanel();
        add(panel);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int squareX = 0;
        private int squareY = 0;
        private int squareW = 20;
        private int squareH = 20;

        private MyPanel() {
            setFocusable(true);
            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                    case (KeyEvent.VK_UP): setyDir(-1);
                    break;
                    case (KeyEvent.VK_DOWN): setyDir(1);
                    break;
                    case (KeyEvent.VK_LEFT): setxDir(-1);
                    break;
                    case (KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT): setxDir(1);
                    break;
                    }
                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                    case (KeyEvent.VK_UP): setyDir(0);
                    break;
                    case (KeyEvent.VK_DOWN): setyDir(0);
                    break;
                    case (KeyEvent.VK_LEFT): setxDir(0);
                    break;
                    case (KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT): setxDir(0);
                    break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void repaintSquare(int x, int y) {
            int OFFSET = 1;
            if ((squareX!=x) || (squareY!=y)) {
                repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
                squareX=x;
                squareY=y;
                repaint(squareX,squareY,squareW+OFFSET,squareH+OFFSET);
            }
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);  
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(squareX,squareY,squareW,squareH);
        }
    }

    private void move() {
        panel.repaintSquare(xPos, yPos);
        xPos += xDir;
        yPos += yDir;
    }

    private void setxDir(int x) {
        this.xDir = x;
    }

    private void setyDir(int y) {
        this.yDir = y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Boxxy());
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                move();
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been discussed in similar questions, don't use a KeyListener, but rather use Key Bindings. A Swing Timer can be used to repeatedly move the sprite.

---

**Edit**
For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EnumMap;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Boxxy2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final int SQUARE_W = 20;
   private static final String PRESSED = "pressed";
   private static final String RELEASED = "released";
   public static final int MOVE_SCALE = 1;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 5;
   private int squareX = 0;
   private int squareY = 0;
   private int squareW = SQUARE_W;
   private int squareH = SQUARE_W;
   private EnumMap<Direction, Boolean> dirMap = new EnumMap<>(Direction.class);

   public Boxxy2() {
      setupKeyBinding();
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   private void setupKeyBinding() {
      int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inMap = getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actMap = getActionMap();

      // this uses an enum of Direction that holds ints for the arrow keys
      for (Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
         dirMap.put(direction, Boolean.FALSE);
         int key = direction.getKey();
         String name = direction.name();

         KeyStroke keyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, 0, false);
         KeyStroke keyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, 0, true);

         // add the key bindings for arrow key and shift-arrow key
         inMap.put(keyPressed, name + PRESSED);
         inMap.put(keyReleased, name + RELEASED);
         actMap.put(name + PRESSED, new MyKeyAction(this, direction, true));
         actMap.put(name + RELEASED, new MyKeyAction(this, direction, false));
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillRect(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Boxxy2 mainPanel = new Boxxy2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Boxxy2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         for (Direction dir : dirMap.keySet()) {
            if (dirMap.get(dir)) {
               squareX += MOVE_SCALE * dir.getRight();
               squareY += MOVE_SCALE * dir.getDown();
            }
         }
         repaint();
      }
   }

   public void setMovement(Direction direction, boolean keyPressed) {
      dirMap.put(direction, keyPressed);
   }
}

enum Direction {
   UP(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, -1), DOWN(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, 1), LEFT(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, -1, 0), RIGHT(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 1, 0);

   private int key;
   private int right;
   private int down;

   private Direction(int key, int right, int down) {
      this.key = key;
      this.right = right;
      this.down = down;
   }

   public int getKey() {
      return key;
   }

   public int getRight() {
      return right;
   }

   public int getDown() {
      return down;
   }

}

// Actions for the key binding
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyKeyAction extends AbstractAction {
   private Boxxy2 boxxy2;
   private Direction direction;
   private boolean keyPressed;

   public MyKeyAction(Boxxy2 boxxy2, Direction direction, boolean keyPressed) {
      this.boxxy2 = boxxy2;
      this.direction = direction;
      this.keyPressed = keyPressed;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      boxxy2.setMovement(direction, keyPressed);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sure it has, but I couldn't find my specific question answered. 

A Swing Timer instead of a thread, or a Swing Timer on top of that? Could you guide me to a similar question?

Nvm, I got it. Thanks for answering so quickly.

Comment: @Mumfi: but using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8961998/522444) of mine as a basis...

Comment: Thank you very much for that code, I will study it more in detail when I have time. You stirred around quite a bit though. Is it a matter of personal style or is your code simply better? Especially when it comes to me using a thread, and you using a timer.