# Why does my KeyListener Lag?

Tags: java, keylistener

So I have a simple KeyListener here:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A&&x>=0) {
    x -= 9;
} 
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D&&x<=1250) {
    x += 9;
}
```

But, after I press D, then it hesitates, then starts to go up.

Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you mean when you press and hold the key? If so, then it's how the OS handles keys. If Swing better to use KeyBindings and a Swing Timer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels How?

Comment: Hard to tell since your question is quite scant on the details of your problem.

Comment: [This answer shows what I mean](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21817447/522444)