# JComboBox Selection disables KeyListener from JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on a small game in Java (Swing). The avatar is controlled with the arrow keys. The main menu contains a `JComboBox`. 
If you don't select something from it the avatar is controllable via the arrow keys. However if you select something new, the `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` won't react on any key press.
What am I missing with the JComboBox? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add pictures of the game so we can understand

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8961998)

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why I didn't find that post